# Transfer between Trysil and Scandinavian Mountains Airport

Tags: airport-transfer, scandinavia, scr, trysil

I've been skiing in Trysil before and back then I took a 6 hour bus there. Today they have an airport and as one who doesn't like charter trips I wonder what the options are for getting from the airport to Trysil and back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sälen Buss](https://salenbuss.savea.se/trysil?lang=en) offers **bus transfers** that must be booked in advance.

You also have the option to transfer on snow with either [**dog sleds** or **snowmobiles**](https://scandinavianmountains.se/en/passengers/transfer/).

Of course there's also **taxi**, **charter busses for groups** and **rental cars**.

---

All options are listen on the airports [website](https://scandinavianmountains.se/en/passengers/transfer/).